# crystal report and sql command

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

i have a problem in showing data content from joined table in crystal report 
my sql query is good and it shown my own  data but i when fill crystal report  datasource and show it  the crystal repeat duplicate and more data 
my code is:

```
   Dim rep As CrystalReport1 = New CrystalReport1()
    Dim objcon = New SqlConnection("data source=(local);initial catalog=hesabres;user id='sa';password='Maysam7026'")
    Dim objcom = New SqlCommand
    Dim objdata As New DataTable
    Dim objdr As SqlDataReader
    objcom.CommandText = " SELECT customer.customer_name, customer.customer_tel, orders.order_stuff_name, orders.order_number" & _
" FROM   hesabres.dbo.orders orders inner JOIN hesabres.dbo.customer customer ON orders.order_customer_id=customer.customer_id"

    objcom.Connection = objcon
    objcon.Open()
    objdr = objcom.ExecuteReader
    objdata.Load(objdr)
    rep.SetDataSource(objdata)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rep
```

Comment: can you attach screen shots of data table valus and crystal report results?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order of these 2 lines 
from:

```
rep.SetDataSource(objdata)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rep
```

to:

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rep
rep.SetDataSource(objdata)
```

Comment: you probably have not set the links between the tables in the report correctly so that's causing extra records to show up in the result. otherwise, trying the above will make sure the data loaded in the report is actually from the the table you are populating (not the pre-defined data source in the report).